# Checking working hours time - Improve code/logic

Tags: php, datetime

I have a system that checks if the current time is working hours in Hong Kong.
I determined that working hours are from 9 AM to 6 PM.
My code is working but i feel like there is a better/prettier way to write the IF condition.

The function will return True when the current time is NOT working time in HK.
It will also return TRUE (as off hours in HK) 15 minutes before the end of the day (6 PM) and will return FALSE (as working hours in HK) 30 minutes before opening time.

```
function hkOffHours($endHour = 18, $startHour = 9) {
    $offHour = FALSE;

    // create the DateTimeZone object for later
    $dtzone = new DateTimeZone('Asia/Hong_Kong');

    // first convert the timestamp into a string representing the local time
    $time = date('r', time());

    // now create the DateTime object for this time
    $dtime = new DateTime($time);

    // convert this to the user's timezone using the DateTimeZone object
    $dtime->setTimeZone($dtzone);

    // print the time using your preferred format
    $time = $dtime->format('g:i A m/d/y');

    $hour = $dtime->format('G');
    $min  = $dtime->format('i');
    $day  = $dtime->format('D');

    // if weekend
    if(($day == 'Sun' || $day == 'Sat') )
    {
       $offHour = TRUE;
    }

    // if out of office hours
    if (
        ($admin_group == '1') &&
        (
           ( $hour == ($endHour-1) && $min>=45 ) ||
           ( $hour >= $endHour ) ||
           ( $hour == ($startHour-1) && $min <= 30 ) ||
           ( $hour <= ($startHour -2))
        )
    ) 
    {
        $offHour = TRUE;  
    } 

    return $offHour;        
}
```

I will appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: your are probably better of at this place: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks, was not familiar with that

Answer (score 0):

Well, my first thought is you could refactor this by breaking it into several methods and a class, if you don't already do this that way.

For example:

```
    $offHour = FALSE;

    // create the DateTimeZone object for later
    $dtzone = new DateTimeZone('Asia/Hong_Kong');

    // first convert the timestamp into a string representing the local time
    $time = date('r', time());

    // now create the DateTime object for this time
    $dtime = new DateTime($time);

    // convert this to the user's timezone using the DateTimeZone object
    $dtime->setTimeZone($dtzone);

    // print the time using your preferred format
    $time = $dtime->format('g:i A m/d/y');

    $hour = $dtime->format('G');
    $min  = $dtime->format('i');
    $day  = $dtime->format('D');
```

All above fields could be class variables.

```
if(($day == 'Sun' || $day == 'Sat') )
```

this could be moved to separate function, called `isWeekend()`

```
if (
    ($admin_group == '1') &&
    (
       ( $hour == ($endHour-1) && $min>=45 ) ||
       ( $hour >= $endHour ) ||
       ( $hour == ($startHour-1) && $min <= 30 ) ||
       ( $hour <= ($startHour -2))
    )
) 
{
    $offHour = TRUE;  
}
```

this could be moved to `isOutOfOfficeHours()`.

Whole class template:

```
class workingHours{

  private $dtzone;
  private ...
  (...)

  public function __construct($dtzone....){
    //setup values of class members
  }

  private function isWeekend(){} //see above

  private function isOutOfOfficeHours(){} //also see above

  public function hkOffHours(){
    return $this->isWeekend() || $this->isOutOfOfficeHours();
  }
}
```

Of course notice that I wrote this quick, I'm at work. Therefore my code logic might be not 100% compatible with yours. Anyway I hope that you'll get the idea.

Also one final thought - there are many books about refactoring. Try one! They'll make you a better coder.

Comment: Thanks, I have no problem with refactoring, but it seems to me a bit of an overkill to build a class or this simple task but will consider it. Thanks

Comment: It might sound like overkill at first but trust me, it's not. I don't know if you had anything to do with bigger projects. I did and found out that this is basically a good practice. Sometimes you're pretty sure that "I will use this method only here". Time passess and you end up with dozen of copies of this or similar methods all over the place. Another thing is by splitting and converting to class, you can always reuse some of it's components, and for example implement strategy pattern (http://bit.ly/1ftdIiM) to get working hours for other countries. This approach also follows DRY rules.

Comment: Thanks @ex3v, basicly i agree with you, maybe i am too lazy or too overloaded to do this as a class, but although there is some logic to build it as a class, i still think there are some places where a old fashion function is good enough- not saying that for bigger things i wont use OOP. in any case, any thoughts on the IF statement, will love to hear your thoughts...